# Odd outline in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, cmyk

I wonder why the circle on the top has weird outline. My zoom is set to 100%. I am working in CMYK color mode and this is my settings.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing anything out of the ordinary... Can you be more precise?

Comment: Yes. It only appears when I use the C0 M0 Y0 K100 value. I tried to zoom it out, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom in farther; you will see there is nothing wrong.

You appear to be referring to a display issue.  The pixels are your screen are little rectangles.  They can only *approximate* a curved line.